# Access elements inside multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array in PHP:

```
array(4) { 
["took"]=> int(2) 
["timed_out"]=> bool(false) 
["_shards"]=> array(3) { 
    ["total"]=> int(5)
    ["successful"]=> int(5)
    ["failed"]=> int(0) 
} 
["hits"]=> array(3) { 
    ["total"]=> int(3) 
    ["max_score"]=> float(2.3578677) 
    ["hits"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(5) { 
            ["_index"]=> string(13) "telephonebook" 
            ["_type"]=> string(6) "person" 
            ["_id"]=> string(22) "M5vJJZasTGG2L_RbCQZcKA" 
            ["_score"]=> float(2.3578677) 
            ["_source"]=> array(8) { 
                ["Mob"]=> string(19) "XXX" 
                ["Title"]=> string(13) "Analyst" 
                ["Department"]=> string(8) "Analysis" 
                ["Country"]=> string(6) "Sweden" 
                ["Tlf"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["Name"]=> string(16) "XXX" 
                ["Email"]=> string(29) "XX@retro.com" 
                ["thumbnailPhoto"]=> string(0) "" 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

}

The array has several  "hits" inside "hits" and I want to loop trough and print out the stuff inside "_source". I have tried a few different approaches but I cant figure out any way to do this. Please help me.

Comment: Did you read the examples in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)? What have you tried after reading them?

Comment: Show us what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ($arr['hits']['hits'] as $val) 
{
   echo $val['_source']['Mob'];

}
```

like this

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($array['hits']['hits'][0]['_source'] as $key => $value) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may handle it for you. Replace $the_array_you_provided with your "main" array variable (you've not specified it in the post).

```
$hits = $the_array_you_provided['hits']['hits'];

foreach ($hits as $hit) {
    echo $hit['_source']['Title'];

    //print everything in the array
    //print_r($hit['_source']);
}
```

Any help feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   foreach ($array['hits']['hits'] as $hit) {
      foreach ($hit['_source'] as $source) {
         echo $source, '<br>';
      }
   }
```